# Using PNGs with Button Controls

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, button, gdi+, direct2d

I am trying to render a PNG on a button control for my dialog box (Visual Studio 2010 Professional). After doing some research, I found the following method which works for BMP files:

```
HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(NULL, L"test.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_BUTTON1), BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap);
```

This does not work with PNG files, though. After some more research, I found that there is a simple way to do this using GDI+:

```
HBITMAP hBitmap;
Gdiplus::Bitmap b(L"a.png");
b.GetHBITMAP(NULL, &hBitmap);

SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_BUTTON1), BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap);
```

I am not using GDI+ anywhere else in my program but I still need to include the headers, link to the library and initialize it just to accomplish this simple task. Is it worth all of this trouble? Is there a more standard way to do this?

I plan to render multiple PNGs (some transparent) on a single button.

EDIT: The (slightly modified) CreateDIBSectionFromBitmapSource() function that I am using to create the HBITMAP can be found here:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=win7wicsamples&DownloadId=7549

Answer (score 0):

Can you be a bit more specific about you mean by "Rendering" a PNG on a button control...

If you mean that you are trying to stick a .PNG image on a button, then yes there is an easier way. Just click on the button and go to 'Appearance in the properties menu. Click on 'BackgroundImage', select local resource, then  browse to the image and load it. Done.

If this isn't what you mean to do, then I might suggest researching

System.Drawing.Image and using the GDI+

I am actually sitting here learning GDI+ as we speak. Be forewarned, it's a time and a half to learn.

Comment: Yeah, I mean sticking a PNG image on a button. I don't see BackgroundImage under Appearance in the properties menu. Does this work for a C++ application using the VS Resource Editor?

Comment: Obviously, System.Drawing.Image is .net stuff, but you want native C++, right?

Comment: Entirely my fault. I saw VS2010 & GDI+ in the question and assumed he was using C#.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that in the post (only have a tiny C++ tag at the bottom). But yes, I am looking for a native C++ solution. If you think you can help, please check out my reply to nanda to see the current state of my issue.

Answer (score 0):

GDI+ is a standard way for reading and rendering images in different format. Other way of doing this would be to create the PNG decoder component and acquiring the stream from it and pass it to LoadImage function, which is exactly what GDI+ does for you in the back ground. The image format encoders and decoders are part of window imaging component.

In terms of how decoding and rendering is going to perform for multiple images depends on what you are looking for and I am not sure about it. Let me just leave a few comments. What you may do and are doing now (through button's back-ground image option) is to decode the images once and keep them as bit map so when painting has to be done the bitmap is ready and no decoding needs to be done. This is what button's back-ground image painting does too, the button component keeps the bitmap handle you pass it and would just paint the same every it has to repaint. I don't think you need to worry about performance of painting a bitmap because it is done using Bitblt to the display device directly.

Comment: I got the PNG to display on the button using WIC. Specifically, I am using a CreateDIBSectionFromBitmapSource() function found in an MSDN sample project to create the HBITMAP. My only question is, how can I display multiple PNG images on the button using transparency? I would like to cycle through a number of PNGs to display on the button with transparency enabled. Is this possible? Please keep in mind that I am quite new to this specific area of programming. :)

Comment: Edited my original post to include a link to the MSDN project with the CreateDIBSectionFromBitmapSource() function that I am using to create the bitmap.